# SVCでload_wineのスコアを出したいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

Tags: python3, 機械学習

まだスケール変換をする前ですが、エラーが出る意味がわかりません。

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

wine = load_wine()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(wine.data, wine.target, stratify=wine.target, 
random_state=42)
svc = SVC()
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(svc.score(X_train, y_train))
print(svc.score(X_test, y_test))
```

何度やってもこのようなエラーが出てしまいます。どなたかわかる方お願いします。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "homework18.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
  File "/Users/iwasakiyoshinobu/Desktop/lesson18/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Users/iwasakiyoshinobu/Desktop/lesson18/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 10, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Users/iwasakiyoshinobu/Desktop/lesson18/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/Users/iwasakiyoshinobu/Desktop/lesson18/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Users/iwasakiyoshinobu/Desktop/lesson18/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/Users/iwasakiyoshinobu/Desktop/lesson18/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Users/iwasakiyoshinobu/Desktop/lesson18/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
  File "/Users/iwasakiyoshinobu/Desktop/lesson18/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .numerictypes import object_
  File "/Users/iwasakiyoshinobu/Desktop/lesson18/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 297, in <module>
    _add_types()
  File "/Users/iwasakiyoshinobu/Desktop/lesson18/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 290, in _add_types
    allTypes[name] = info.type
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Comment: `scikit-learn`のバージョンはいくつでしょうか? 私の環境で、`0.19.2`版をインストールしてご質問のコードを実行すると、エラーは発生せずに`1.0`と`0.4`が出力されました。

Comment: from sklearn.datasets import load_wine の所でnumpy絡みのエラーが出ています。numpyを高速化のために別にコンパイルしたものをインストールして、sklearnの方はpipで普通にバイナリー(wheel)のパッケージをインストールしているようなことはないでしょうか？

Comment: 解決いたしました！

ありがとうございました！

Comment: 解決してよかったです。回答の方に書いておきます。

Answer (score 1):

コードには問題はありませんが、1行目の`from sklearn.datasets import load_wine`で`sklearn`が`numpy`を呼び出しているところでエラーが出ています。ということは`sklearn`と`numpy`のパッケージに問題があるということです。

`sklearn`は処理を高速にするため`Cython`等で書かれたパッケージなので、`sklearn`と`numpy`が異なるコンパイラーやライブラリーを使ってコンパイルされたものを使っているためバイナリーでの互換性に問題が発生したということが考えられます。

`numpy`は、高速化のため、IntelのMKLを使うように自分でコンパイルしたり、IntelのPythonを使ったりすることがありますが、その場合には、`sklearn`も同じ方法でコンパイルしたものを使う必要があります。